# C++ program using vector of pointers of inherited classes compile but doesn't run

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an abstract class called box that only has a string parameter called type and a virtual string that only returns that parameter. This class is the father of another class called Reward that has the constructor that fills the the parameter type and the same function of Box. I'm trying to put them in a class called Board that is basically a vector of the pointers of these classes, I have a constructor that just fills the vector with rewards. The problem comes that I compille it but doesn't run and I cannot find where is the problem. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Box{
protected:
  string type;
public:
  virtual string getType()=0;
};

class Reward : public Box{
public:
  string getType(){
    return type;
  }
  Reward(){
    type = "Reward";
  }
};

class Board{
private:
  vector<Box *> Table;
public:
  Board(){
    for (int i=0;i<=30;i++){
      Table[i]=new Reward;
    }
  }
  string getBoxes(int i){
    return Table[i]->getType();
  }
};


int main(){
  Board game;
  string toPrint=game.getBoxes(2);
  cout<<toPrint;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a *debugger* to see if you have a crash? If not, then use the debugger to step through your code statement by statement, stepping into all your own functions, to see what really happens.

Comment: A hint though: Vectors start out *empty*. All indexing (even index `0`) will be out of bounds. Now please take some time to go through your text books, class notes or tutorials and see what they say about adding elements to a vector.

Comment: I had a bigger program and didnt seem to make a difference the push_back function, but now it does. Thanks

Comment: C++ doesn't have bound-checking for array-indexing (`std::vector` have using the `at` function). Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*, which unfortunately sometimes *might* seem to work.

Comment: Do not know the logic of your code, but the line Table[i]=new Reward; is an error. You did not resize vector<Box *> Table; after you created it, so its size is =0 and you try to insert a value in an empty container. (no Table[i] exists yet). You should use Table.push_back(new Reward);. Then the output is "Reward".

Comment: Note that since `getType()` will just return the value of the `type` variable there is no need to make it virtual pure (it can still be virtual to allow subclasses to do something more, but probably in most cases you just want to return the value of `type`). Just add the implementation of `getType()` in the `Box` class as well as a nondefault constructor that receives the value of `type`. Then each subclass will be forced to explicitly call the `Box` constructor passing the correct value for `type` in their constructor's initializer list.

Comment: Yes, it's a bigger program but it's the most basic structure that I will use